# Convert comma separated string to array without string split?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

Using Java, how would I convert "Paul, John, Ringo" to

Paul

John

Ringo

But while using a loop that searches for the commas and pulls out the words between them? I can't use anything like string split, strictly a loop and pretty simple java. Thanks!

Comment: Read about indexOf and substring methods in String class

Comment: Java or Javascript? `str.match(/\w+/g);`

Comment: `"Paul, John, Ringo".match(/[^,]+/g)`

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> list = new List<String>();
String text = "your, text, here";
int indexTraversed = 0;
while(true){
int i = text.indexOf(",", indexTraversed);
if(i<0) break;
list.add(text.substring(indexTraversed, i));
indexTraversed += i + 1;
}
String[] array = list.toArray();
```

and if you can't use List :

```
String[] list = new String[100];
int counter = 0;
String text = "your, text, here";
int indexTraversed = 0; // declaring and assigning var
while(true){
int i = text.indexOf(",", indexTraversed);
if(i<0) break;
list.add(text.substring(indexTraversed, i));
indexTraversed += i + 1;
counter ++;
}
```

Then read the list array until counter.

Answer (score 0):

```
    String str = "Paul, John, Ringo";
    List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    int cIndex = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
        if (str.charAt(i) == ',') {
            String temp = str.substring(cIndex, i).trim();
            cIndex = i + 1;
            words.add(temp);
        }
    }
    String temp = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf(',')+1,str.length()).trim();
    words.add(temp);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! that makes so much sense. how then would i return the new array list?

Comment: You can just do 
        return words;

Or you could convert it to an array and return that by
        for(int i=0;i<wordsArray.length;i++)
   wordsArray[i]=words.get(i);
        return wordsArray;